# Get value of last expression in `exec` call

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have some python code in a string

```
code = """
a = 42
a
"""
```

and I `exec` that string of code:

```
result = exec(code)
```

Then `result` will always be `None`. Is there any way at all to get the value of the last expression evaluated? In this case, that would be `5`, since `a` was the last expression.

EDIT: Here's another example of the functionality I'm asking about. Let's say we have the python code (stored in the variable `code`)

```
a = 100
sqrt(a)
```

Then how can I execute the code in such a way as to give me the result `10` - that is, `sqrt(a)`?

EDIT EDIT: A further example: the code I wish to `exec` is

```
function_a()
function_b()
function_c()
```

Is there any way I can define some kind of `magic_exec` function so that

```
magic_exec(code)
```

will provide me with the value of `function_c()`?

Comment: There's a good chance that you have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: I don't think so.The problem I have is that I want to be able to "see" the result of execution of arbitrary Python code. What `exec` gives me (`None`) is not useful for that purpose. I want a value that _is_ useful for that purpose.

Comment: Execution of arbitrary Python code doesn't even necessarily _have_ a result. For example, `exec('pass')`. Are you asking this out of curiosity, or are you working out an algorithm for an actual program?

Comment: If you parse the newlines yourself and pass individual commands to `eval` instead of `exec`, that seems to do what you want.

Comment: @JohnGordon unless I have multiple statements and expressions interspersed, or even a single expression spread over multiple lines. Anyway, I hope there's a solution that's simpler than parsing and evaluating code myself, but maybe I'll just have to bite the bullet on that one.

Comment: Do you need your namespace to be updated by the `exec` call? If not, you might be able to pass in a dictionary and get what you want out of it at the end.

Answer (score 8):

The request is certainly valid because I need such a function as well during the creation of a Python-based environment. I solved the problem with the following code that utilizes the Python ast mechanism:

```
def my_exec(script, globals=None, locals=None):
    '''Execute a script and return the value of the last expression'''
    stmts = list(ast.iter_child_nodes(ast.parse(script)))
    if not stmts:
        return None
    if isinstance(stmts[-1], ast.Expr):
        # the last one is an expression and we will try to return the results
        # so we first execute the previous statements
        if len(stmts) > 1:
            exec(compile(ast.Module(body=stmts[:-1]), filename="<ast>", mode="exec"), globals, locals)
        # then we eval the last one
        return eval(compile(ast.Expression(body=stmts[-1].value), filename="<ast>", mode="eval"), globals, locals)
    else:
        # otherwise we just execute the entire code
        return exec(script, globals, locals)
```

The code should be pretty self-explanatory, basically it

1. separate the script into multiple statements
2. if the last one is an expression, execute the first part as statements, and the last part as expression.
3. Otherwise execute the entire script as statements.

Comment: I agree that "The request is certainly valid", I had a very similar use case.

Answer (score 3):

For new comers modified [user2283347](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2283347/user2283347) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47130538/19632881) with modern Python and some edge cases:

```py
def exec_with_return(code: str, globals:dict, locals:dict) -> ... | None:
    a = ast.parse(code)
    last_expression = None
    if a.body:
        if isinstance(a_last := a.body[-1], ast.Expr):
            last_expression = ast.unparse(a.body.pop())
        elif isinstance(a_last, ast.Assign):
            last_expression = ast.unparse(a_last.targets[0])
        elif isinstance(a_last, (ast.AnnAssign, ast.AugAssign)):
            last_expression = ast.unparse(a_last.target)
    exec(ast.unparse(a), globals, locals)
    if last_expression:
        return eval(last_expression, globals, locals)
```

Some explanation notes:

- We use `ast.unparse` instead of compilation, because we really want to unparse but compile.
- We also want assignments at the last line of code to return values, e.g. `x=1` returns `1` instead of `None`.
- Actually we do not bare of specific cases in the last line, we just unparse targets (variable names, object attributes, dict indexes or other "value storages") and evaluate them.
- From the above we assume (and it is 99% truth) that any "value storage" setter must also have getter.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec('a = 4')
print a % prints 4

>>> code = """
... a = 42
... b = 53"""
>>> exec(code)
>>> a
42
>>> b
53
```

Or if you're saying you don't know the last thing is b for instance, then you can have this:

```
code = """  
a = 4
b = 12
abc_d=13
"""
t = re.findall(r'''.*?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s*?=.*?$''', code)
assert(len(t)==1)
print t[0] % prints 13
```

Comment: See my edit. What if I have an arbitrary expression that is being evaluated? How can I get its value from an `exec` call?

Comment: I think you still don't see what I'm getting at - I'm sorry if my question is not clear. Let's say that I don't have a variable assignment at all. I only have two function calls in the code that I'm evaluating (`a() \n b()`). How can I define some kind of `magic_exec` function that will run `a()` and `b()` _and then give me the value_ of `b()` instead of `None`?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't get you the last evaluated value, but gets the whole list of local variables.

```
>>> loc = {}
>>> exec(code, {}, loc)
>>> loc
{'a': 42}
```

Comment: I know that I can access the variables defined in the `exec` call. Let's say that the last expression evaluated is not simply a variable. If the last expression is `sqrt(4)` I would like to receive `2` as the result instead of `None`. That's what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I can't say I'm very happy with this. It feels very hacky and I haven't tested it all that heavily. On the other hand I'm quite pleased with it. Was quite fun to do. Anyway, hope this helps you or at least comes close to what you want. `locals()` gives a dict so the output list order does not match the input order for the items that failed the first `eval`. If you don't want `';'` as delimiters then you can change it to `'\n'`.

```
import math

def magic_exec(_command):
    _command = _command.split(';')
    _result = None
    _before = list(locals()) # Get list of current local variables

    for _code in _command:
        _code = _code.strip() # .strip() prevent IndentationError
        try:
            if eval(_code) != None: # For functions with no return
                _result = eval(_code)
        except (NameError, SyntaxError):
            try:
                _before = list(locals())
                exec(_code)
            except NameError as e: # For undefined variables in _command
                print("An Error Occurred with line ' {0} ' as was skipped: {1}".format(_code, e))

    del _code # delete temp var _code
    # Get new list of locals that didn't exist at the start
    _after = [val for val in list(locals()) if val not in _before]

    if _after:
        return eval(_after[0])
    else:
        return _result

#Dummy class and functions
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def get_val(self):
        return self._x

    def __repr__(self):
        return type(self).__name__

def func1(x):
    return x + x

def func2(x):
    print(x*x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code = \
"""
a = 42; a; v; y = 2; b = func1(5); s = 'Hello'; func2(10); c = 25; l = []; l.append('Value');
t = math.sqrt(c); pass; 20*10; print('TEST'); math.sqrt(c); d = Class1('World'); d.get_val(); 
def func3(x): return x ** 2; s = func3(15)
"""
    values = magic_exec(code)
    print(values)
```

Comment: I like the idea, but there are many complications. What if commands are not separated by semicolons? What if there are semicolons in the code (such as in comments or strings) that are not meant to separate commands? I hop there's an easier way than dealing with a Python AST myself, but I think your solution works only for relatively simple cases.

Comment: Even if lines are separated by newlines and/or semicolons, I think the kind of parsing you do (split on newlines/semicolons) could break working code easily.

Comment: Would you really be passing in comments though? I don't think you can. The split of `;` delimiter works as in python a new line of code can be represented using `;`. It just breaks if a semi-colon is used in a string. Separating by ';' is a limit on this as well. You can use `\n` assuming you space it out correctly, but again it breaks on strings with `\n` char

Comment: But that is a very real use case. I need a solution that works for _any_ arbitrary Python code. I like your idea, but I think the parsing would need to be much more complicated in order to make it work.

Comment: And why can't the input string of code have comments in it? It's just a string, after all...

Comment: Your question though was to get a return value from `magic_exec(code)` and in examples provided you only used 1 liners like tested

Comment: Ah. Sorry that wasn't clear. I'm given any (valid) Python code, and I want to execute it and get the last expression evaluated. Kind of a cross between `exec` and `eval`, I suppose.

Comment: Well I edited it to give last expression evaluated. (I at least think it's working right) will still break with `; or \n` in strings though. Turns out you can have comments with is cool. Only single line though `#`. I guess you could initially iterate though the code provided and add a special character set at EOL to split at

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to user2283347's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47130538) that it works only up to Python 3.7. In Python 3.8 the signature of `ast.Module.__init__` has changed. It now requires a second argument which in our case can be an empty list.

Details: `ast.Module(body=stmts[:-1])` in

```
    if len(stmts) > 1:
        exec(compile(ast.Module(body=stmts[:-1]), filename="<ast>", mode="exec"), globals, locals)
```

has to be changed to

`ast.Module(stmts[:-1], [])` if you use Python 3.8 or above (note the second argument `[]`). Otherwise the following `TypeError` will be raised:

`TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module`

Unfortunately this change is not very well documented. I found the solution after extensive Googling here: ["IPython broken on 3.8-dev"](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11590) .