# Python: exec() a code block and eval() the last line

Tags: python

I have a string literal containing one or more lines of (trusted) Python code, and I would like to `exec()` the block, while capturing the results of the last line. More concretely, I would like a function `exec_then_eval` that returns the following:

```
code = """
x = 4
y = 5
x + y
"""

assert exec_then_eval(code) == 9
```

A couple things I've tried:

1. By splitting off the last line, you can exec the first block, then eval the last line; e.g.

   ```
   def exec_then_eval(code):
       first_block = '\n'.join(code.splitlines()[:-1])
       last_line = code.splitlines()[-1]
       globals = {}
       locals = {}
       exec(first_block, globals, locals)
       return eval(last_line, globals, locals)
   ```

   This works, but will fail if the last statement has multiple lines.
2. If the code itself is modified so the result is stored as a local variable, this variable can then be recovered; e.g.

   ```
   code = """
   x = 4
   y = 5
   z = x + y
   """

   globals = {}
   locals = {}
   exec(code, globals, locals)
   assert locals['z'] == 9
   ```

   again, this works, but only if you're able to first parse the code block in a general way and modify it appropriately.

Is there an easy way to write a general `exec_and_eval` function?

Comment: I don't think there will be an easy way to do this, though you might be able to get somewhere using https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

Comment: Any particular reason your input has to look like this?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33908794/2301450

Comment: @user2357112 – Yes, the input needs to look like this. Long story short, I'm trying to write a custom sphinx directive to ease the creation of useful documentation of the Altair project, and modification of the code strings would lead to either confusing docs or a brittle sphinx directive.

Comment: @vaultah – thanks, that does look like a similar question, though I think I've asked it in a clearer way. And none of the proposed solutions there seem all that useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on @kalzekdor's suggestion of using the `ast` module, I came up with this solution which is similar in spirit to @vaultah's solution posted above:

```
import ast

def exec_then_eval(code):
    block = ast.parse(code, mode='exec')

    # assumes last node is an expression
    last = ast.Expression(block.body.pop().value)

    _globals, _locals = {}, {}
    exec(compile(block, '<string>', mode='exec'), _globals, _locals)
    return eval(compile(last, '<string>', mode='eval'), _globals, _locals)
```

It also passes @vaultah's nice set of test-cases:

```
exec_then_eval('''x = 4
y = 5
x + y''')) # 9

exec_then_eval('''x = 4
y = 5;x + y''')) # 9

exec_then_eval('''x = 4
y = 5;(
x + y *

2)''') # 14
```

Comment: Great answer! You should accept it, I definitely won't mind.

Comment: I just realized that this is the only correct answer, which works even when the last expression is a multiline string. Mine doesn't, so please unaccept it.

Comment: If you insist!-