# eval after exec: seemingly same strings do not provide the same result (may be encoding problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, eval

I defined the `_exec_` function for getting the output of a function represented by a string.
For instance the `sgn` function evaluated with the `arg` value (see code below).
Then I will have to perform a single eval in the end.
(Warning: `exec` or `eval` of unknown code must be secured before use.)

```
def _exec_(thecode):
    local = {}
    exec(thecode, globals(), local)
    return local["_output_"]

sgn = "\nif _input_[0]<0:\n    _output_ = -1\nif _input_[0]==0:\n    _output_ = 0\nif _input_[0]>0:\n    _output_ = 1"
arg = "[5]"

code_list = ["_input_ = "+arg+sgn]
print(eval("1+_exec_(code_list[0])"))
```

The last 2 lines provide the good result.
However I will have to use it for an undetermined number of times with various "string-functions" and "string-arguments".
Is it possible to do it with only 1 named string instead of a list of strings?

I tried:

```
code = "1+_exec_(_input_ = "+arg+sgn+")"
print(eval(code))
```

which lead to `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
Maybe the encoding of special characters is wrong, then I tried:

```
code = "1+_exec_(_input_ = "+arg+sgn.encode('unicode-escape').decode()+")"
print(eval(code))
```

which lead to `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`.
I also tried to use the answer to [Python: exec() a code block and eval() the last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379331/python-exec-a-code-block-and-eval-the-last-line), without success.

Comment: Which version of the Python interpreter are you trying to run with? (Just not wanting to waste time testing against the wrong major version of the language).

Comment: I should have precised it: Python 3-x.

Comment: That said, after `code = "1+_exec_(_input_ = "+arg+sgn+")"`, run `print(code)` and the cause of the error is pretty clear. It doesn't look like something that _should_ be valid syntax.

Comment: I saw that `:` seems to cause trouble, that's why I tried to change the encoding, ending with another error. I have to say I'm quite new to Python.

Comment: Might I ask why you're trying to use `eval` here? Generally, using it at all is considered a "code smell" -- an indicator that there's probably a better way to accomplish the same goal. (Remember that Python has first-class functions -- you can pass them around, assign them to variables, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As mentionned in the question, I have to eval some arguments and functions that I get as str. Possibly millions of times. Thus I'm looking for a way to do it with the lowest execution time.

Answer (score 1):

They **aren't** the same strings, "seemingly" or otherwise. Just take the `eval` out of both `print(eval(...))` calls and compare:

```
>>> print("1+_exec_(code_list[0])")
1+_exec_(code_list[0])
```

vs:

```
>>> code = "1+_exec_(_input_ = "+arg+sgn+")"
>>> print(code)
1+_exec_(_input_ = [5]
if _input_[0]<0:
    _output_ = -1
if _input_[0]==0:
    _output_ = 0
if _input_[0]>0:
    _output_ = 1)
```

That latter one doesn't look anything like something that might be expected to be valid syntax.