# How to get return value of exec?

Tags: python

How would I do the following:

```
>>> new=exec('i=100;2 if i > 4 else 3')
>>> repr(new)
'None'
```

I want to get `2`:

```
>>> i=100
>>> 2 if i>4 else 3
2
```

I can do this with `eval`, as long as there isn't an assignment:

```
>>> new=eval('2 if i>4 else 3')
>>> new
2
```

In other words, how to execute a string of code (with an assignment, not just `eval`) and get the last part?

---

Here is a related question from ~5 years ago: not sure if the answers still apply though, or anything has changed since then: [How do I get the return value when using Python exec on the code object of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23917776/651174).

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @ppwater 2..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `dict` to be used for the global namespace. Assign the result to a global variable and you can read it later.

```
>>> data = {}
>>> exec('i=100;result = 2 if i > 4 else 3', data)
>>> data['result']
2
```

By default `exec` uses the module's namespace. If you don't mind the exec'd script's variables messing with your own variables, you could leave the global dict out.

```
>>> exec('i=100;result = 2 if i > 4 else 3')
>>> result
2
```

You run the risk of accidentally overwriting data unexpectedly if you don't notice the use of a variable in the string. But its certainly an option.

You can also use 2 dictionaries, one for globals and one for locals and the variables you create will end up in the latter.

```
>>> data1={}
>>> data2={}
>>> exec('i=100;result = 2 if i > 4 else 3', data1, data2)
>>> data2
{'i': 100, 'result': 2}
```

Notice that all of the variables you create in the executed script end up in the namespace dictionaries.

Comment: that's great, I can just add in `result=` to the last statement and it'll give me exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Just split on semicolon into two parts:

```
exec('i=100')
new=eval('2 if i>4 else 3')
```

Comment: ah, I see that's pretty neat. So basically go through the (string) statement and if there's an `=` operator in it split until the next `;` and put that in `exec`, otherwise put it in `eval` ?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379331/python-exec-a-code-block-and-eval-the-last-line) you'll find a more general solution along these lines. (Can't immediately find anyone else using semicolons like that in Python, though.)